# Why are my Apex Legends lobbies so good?

Tags: apex-legends

I have been playing a lot of Apex lately, and I cannot believe the levels and skill of some of the players I play against. I wonder if there are only two types of lobbies, low lobbies or "smurf" lobbies, or the lobbies that are the ones I am in, the "higher lobbies". This question comes with good reason, as I can't seem to get kills anymore. I am a level 26 Seer main, and my KDR has dropped almost two. I just can't seem to figure out why everyone is 400 levels ahead of me with a 4k badge.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351879/why-am-i-suddenly-being-matched-with-high-level-players-in-apex-legends

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I suddenly being matched with high level players in Apex Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351879/why-am-i-suddenly-being-matched-with-high-level-players-in-apex-legends)